# Bootable USB creator for Linux

Tags: linux

Is there a Linux version of http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ for example?

A GUI way to creating a bootable USB stick.

Comment: I recently downloaded A hydrid CD/usb live Debian7, and then used it to install it self to another USB, just the same as if installing to a hard disk. I had to manually choose the correct place to put grub (I thing it defaulted to first hard disk, if so be careful), but that was all, in all other ways it was same as installing to hard disk.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

The current shiny tool, is [`ventoy`](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html). which allow you to create a multi-iso USB disks, and you can boot directly from the ISO, without the need to extract the image.

Just need to format the USB device with the tools, and it will create 2 partions, one for booting and the other to host all the ISO.

Read the [`docs`](https://www.ventoy.net/en/doc_news.html) to what you can do with this tool.

---

OLD answer:

Many Linux distro's have a LiveCD ISO which you can dump with `dd` directly to a USB stick. But a diffrent aproch which i like more is to use GRUB2 to boot LiveCD ISO directly, This will allow you to have several distos/tools on a single USB stick.

Google for Multi ISO GRUB2, and you'll find few tools a guides.

Answer (score 1):

[UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) works on Linux.  It also provides the option to download a distro as part of the process.

Answer (score 0):

usb-creator-gtk is what I use for such tasks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startup_Disk_Creator
Timothy Martin's answer (UNetbootin) seems to be a better solution for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other suggestions, [`bootiso`](http://github.com/jsamr/bootiso/) is a friendly script to achieve such goal in seconds, securely.

Just do:

```
curl -L https://rawgit.com/jsamr/bootiso/latest/bootiso -O
chmod +x bootiso
./bootiso --help
```

Use it like this:

```
./bootiso my-iso-file.iso
```

Answer (score -1):

Etcher is a pretty clean and easy click through GUI.